# How to use non id dynamic segments in ember router?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have a question regarding non id based dynamic segments in the ember router.
I am using Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.1

I have a nested resource, and I need to use a url parameter in the path instead of an id.
but the ajax call to the json api needs to request an id.

So in my handlebars template I have:

```
{{#each thing in controller}}
    {{#linkTo 'thing' thing.url}}{{thing.name}}{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

The things route looks like this:

```
App.ThingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
    model: function() {
        return App.Thing.find(); 
    }
});
```

and the router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('things', function() {
        this.resource('thing', {path:':thing_url'}); 
    });
});
```

How do I map the url to resolve to the things id?

Answer (score 0):

Fred is right. The model hook takes a params argument. Here is a more complete example.

```
App.ThingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Thing.find(params.thing_url);
  }
});
```

Comment: Because you are not searching by id, but by other field, the `find` line should be: `return App.Thing.find('url', params.thing_url);`

Comment: Perhaps my question is not clear enough. The JSON endpoint that relates to this resource is serving an instance of 'thing' using id. This means that ember has to make requests back to the server by id, however I want to display the 'thing' using it's url parameter. I have already downloaded a collection of 'things', so my question is can I relate the 'thing' routes back to that collection to do a lookup by id? Otherwise the server will return 404 because (for example) the route mydomain.com/things/thing_url does not exist but mydomain.com/things/1 does.

Comment: so in this case you also want to implement the serialize method. And do something like like: `return {id: object.get('url')}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already loaded all `Thing`s then you can use `all` method to retrieve all existing models and [`findProperty`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_findProperty) method to find array item by specific property:

```
App.ThingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Thing.all().findProperty('url', params.thing_url);
    }
});
```

Note that this will not work if required model is not loaded - the `findProperty` returns `undefined` if model is not in array and no request to server will be generated.

Answer (score -1):

The model method has a parameter that gets passed in which would be thing.url in this case so you shold be able to access it there.

Read dynamic model part here
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/